# ANSI_NULLS  flag in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I can change the value of `SET ANSI_NULLS` by using `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` or `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`

<kbd>Question #1</kbd>  how can I get the *current* value ?

<kbd>Question #2</kbd>  does setting a value is applied to query? Table? Instance? Whole db?

<kbd>Question #3</kbd> If I'm entering a company which does `if myNullParam <>null`, what is the place which I should check (db ? schema? query ?) to tell them - *this gonna work  , or Not* ?

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `select databasepropertyex('MyDatabaseName', 'IsAnsiNullsEnabled')` will tell you the database default.  Hitesh's answer will tell you the value for the current session.
2. The database has a default settting, and each session can override the database default.
3. The session value.  However, the MSDN documentation says `For a script to work as intended, regardless of the ANSI_NULLS database option or the setting of SET ANSI_NULLS, use IS NULL and IS NOT NULL in comparisons that might contain null values.`  So while it may work, it's certainly against best practices.

Comment: your query doesnt work , as opposed to  Hitesh'es http://i.stack.imgur.com/HufaY.jpg

Comment: @RoyiNamir: How about specifying *your* database's name? :)

Comment: (Just for completeness) The documentation also says: `In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will always be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error`.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: `0` meaning `OFF`, I presume?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: yes, you have to change 'MyDatabaseName' to the name of the database you're checking the value for.

Comment: @AndriyM yes , and the former solution says its on. ( which is true)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It's off for the DB and on for the session, probably.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: `SET ANSI_NULLS` changes the setting for the *session* and doesn't affect it for the *database* (the session's setting takes precedence over the database's, that's what Dan said in #3). To change it for the database, you use `ALTER DATABASE` with a corresponding clause.

Comment: @AndriyM yeah i was just gonna tell you guys - the final solution. Dan's solution is working ONLY regards setting the DB option while Hitesh solution is for the SESSION ONLY  - ignoring the DB option value . ( 100% after testing).

Comment: now im having trouble selecting the selected answer but i guess my question hasnt been asked right ( due to  - unknowing it can be set on session  && db).....so i will select the one who answered ALL the 3 question.

Comment: Why is the default in SQL Server 2012 ANSI_NULLS OFF (false in database options) if they're going to force it ON in future versions?

Answer (score 5):

Answer 1

You can run below query to get if ANSI_NULLS is set or not.

```
DECLARE @options INT
SELECT @options = @@OPTIONS
IF ( (32 & @options) = 32 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULLS'
```

if prints `ANSI_NULLS` then `ANSI_NULLS` is set or it is not set.

you can find more help here http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1415/determining-set-options-for-a-current-session-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

you can use this query to get the property of a given database:

```
SELECT is_ansi_nulls_on FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'yourDatabase'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check all the settings by below metioned

dbcc useroptions