# ansi_nulls: some ways to check it don't seem to work

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-null

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) states that the database ANSI_NULLS flag controls the behavior of comparisons with null on some side.

I was checking [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272733/ansi-nulls-flag-in-sql-server) to check how to *determine* (not set) the value of this flag. Interestingly, not all of the answers seemed to work for me.

My test query:

```
create table x(id int,txt nvarchar(max))
insert x(id,txt) values (1,'not null here'),(2,null)
select * from x

--query 1
select * from x where txt=null

--query 2
select * from x where txt<>null
```

The output returned is two empty result sets. From this, I can logically deduce ANSI_NULLS is ON in my database.

Now, to the checking options:

## 1

`select databasepropertyex('MyDatabaseName', 'IsAnsiNullsEnabled')`

Returns 0. I did not expect this.

## 2

```
DECLARE @options INT
SELECT @options = @@OPTIONS
IF ( (32 & @options) = 32 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULLS'
```

Prints "ANSI_NULLS". Expected.

## 3

`SELECT is_ansi_nulls_on FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'MyDatabaseName'`

Returns 0. I did not expect this.

## 4

`dbcc useroptions`

The results set includes a row with [Set Option]='ansi_nulls' and [Value]='Set'. Expected.

---

**Why do do options 1 and 3 give me this result?**

My @@version is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64) 
    Jun 15 2019 00:26:19 
    Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: Because the connection setting overrides the database default

Comment: @Martin Smith Can you post an answer with more details, please? How can I check the connection setting? I guess this question is dependent on the application used, so let me clarify that I am asking about SSMS.

Comment: I strongly, however, recommend never turning ANSI NULLs off. The ability to do so is to be removed from SQL Server anyway, and `NULL = NULL` is *meant* to **not** be true.

Comment: If you want to compare with NULL, let's write this:
**
select * from x where EXISTS(SELECT txt INERSECT SELECT null)
**

Comment: @Larnu I am aligned with your opinion. Actually, this whole research is just to make me feel "secure" that I can write code which can safely assume this flag being always on (at least when nooone changed it on purpose)

Comment: You will get a result set when you change "=null" and "<>null" to "is null" and "is not null"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your queries are looking at two different things.

One is the database default (can be changed with `ALTER DATABASE SET`) - the other is what it is set to in the current session.

The database default is practically useless as all [common](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40908084/73226) ways of connecting to SQL Server set `ANSI_NULLS` on [as described below](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Connection-level settings that are set by using the SET statement
>   override the default database setting for ANSI_NULLS. ODBC and OLE DB
>   clients issue a connection-level SET statement setting ANSI_NULLS to
>   ON for the session, by default. The clients run the statement when you
>   connect to an instance of SQL Server. For more information, see SET
>   ANSI_NULLS.

Answer (score 0):

for the session:

```
set ansi_nulls on;

select sessionproperty('ANSI_NULLS');

select ansi_nulls
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where session_id = @@spid;

select case when null=null then 0 else 1 end;
-------------
set ansi_nulls off;

select sessionproperty('ANSI_NULLS');

select ansi_nulls
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where session_id = @@spid;

select case when null=null then 0 else 1 end;
```